# Why does focusing feel less accurate to me on the Canon 600D than the 60D?

Tags: focus, canon-60d, canon-600d

Is there a substantial (or minor) difference in the focusing in 60D and 600D. I tried both in a showroom and felt (I may be wrong) that there was a difference. The focusing I felt was very quick and sharp in 60D. It's funny, but I felt the focusing was not accurate in 600D though the result at least in the preview showed that photo did focus correctly.

I am really confused between 600D and 60D and have to buy one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you have t buy one of the two and there is no difference for you, **get the 60D**. It is a more advanced camera and much easier to control because of that, although image quality is very similar.

The perception of better focus from the viewfinder probably comes from the the fact it is more than 10% larger. **The bigger the viewfinder, the more details you can see and that contributes to your perception.**

The **60D has a more sophisticated autofocus system so I expect it to be faster**. The 60D has more sensitive (cross-type) focus-points so it can detect autofocus faster. If you switch to center-only focus-point, the difference will diminish, as you will be measuring cross-type vs cross-type AF speed. That does not mean it will be the same, just closer.

Finally, you did not say if the same lens was used on both cameras. That can make a huge difference. If it was not, then no comparison of focus speed would have much validity.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you used the autofocus and under which circumstances (and hopefully with the same lens). The 60D has 9 [cross type sensors](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9785/whats-the-difference-between-cross-type-autofocus-points-and-regular-ones) to focus, the 600D only the one in the center.

If you have the money to spare and the need: the 60D is environmentally sealed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes,  i used both with the same lens (18-135). In 60D the focus was instant and visibly crisp and sharp while in 600D it was not.
I sure have the extra money for 60D but what i am debating is the clear advantage:
1. Extra Speed in 60D is something i think is rarely achievable, so not a big deal.
2. More sturdy body, according to me is not a big deal, Infact i liked the smaller and lighter 600D
3.  BUT the focus in 600D as noticed by me really sucked, and that is what i need to settle before i finalise the camera for me.
cheers