# What apertures are required to enable autofocus, including cross-type or high-precision focusing, on Canon DSLR cameras?

Tags: canon, autofocus, aperture, performance

*This is a follow-up to [Why does Canon and Nikon limit or disable autofocus beyond certain f-numbers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/why-does-canon-limit-or-disable-autofocus-below-certain-f-numbers)  I'm doing this to separate the AF aperture requirements from the linked question above.  My goal here is to create a canonical answer for Canon AF aperture limits, with complete information for every Canon EOS model since the EOS D30.*

What apertures are required for Canon EOS DSLR cameras to autofocus?  What apertures are needed to enable cross-type and/or high-precision autofocus?

---

#### Answer navigation

- [General information and APS-C cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr/16400#16400)
- [Full frame and APS-H cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr/56817#56817)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

*To increase readability and avoid exceeding the answer length limit, this answer has been split across two posts. General information and APS-C cameras are covered in this post; full-frame and APS-H cameras [are covered in a separate post below](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr/56817#56817).*

---

---

### TL;DR answer

In general, Canon DSLRs require a maximum aperture of at least f/5.6 or wider to autofocus, although EOS-1 series cameras and certain newer models (including the EOS 5D Mark III, EOS 7D Mark II, and EOS 80D; essentially, any model with an AF sensor that has 45 or more points) are capable of focusing at f/8 with the center focus point. Depending on the camera model, and with some exceptions, a maximum aperture at least f/2.8 or f/4 or wider enables cross-type and/or high-precision focusing.

---

### Definitions

- A **horizontal-sensitive point** or **vertical-sensitive point** is an autofocus point that can detect horizontal or vertical lines, respectively. A horizontal-sensitive point cannot detect vertical lines, and a vertical-sensitive point cannot detect horizontal lines.
- A **single-line point** is a horizontal-sensitive point or a vertical-sensitive point.
- A **high-precision sensor** is an autofocus sensor that is capable of focusing within 1/3 of the depth of field of the lens, instead of simply within the depth of field. These sensors require faster maximum apertures, typically f/2.8 or wider, in order for them to work.
- A **cross-type point** is an autofocus point that can detect both horizontal and vertical lines simultaneously. Cross-type points are actually two single-line points superimposed over one another at a 90 degree angle. Depending on the camera model, the maximum aperture may need to be at least as wide as f/2.8 or f/4 for a point to be cross-type, because the vertical-sensitive part of the AF point may be a high-precision sensor.
- A **dual cross-type point** is an autofocus point that can detect diagonal lines as well as horizontal and vertical lines. Dual cross-type points are a cross-type point superimposed over another cross type point at a 45 degree angle. The diagonal sensors require an f/2.8 or wider lens in order to function because they are high-precision sensors.

#### Important notes

Where "autofocus does not function" is noted, phase-detection autofocus is normally impossible, either when shooting through the viewfinder or with the Quick AF mode in Live View, but it is generally possible to autofocus using the contrast detection-based Live AF and Face Detection Live AF modes in Live View.

In addition, when an extender (teleconverter) is being used and the resulting aperture is less than what is normally required for AF, it may be possible to enable AF by taping the three extender-specific pins (which are opposite of the raised pins) on the lens side of the extender to prevent it from communicating extender information with the lens and camera, so that the camera sees the lens's aperture as though no extender is attached. This is not guaranteed to succeed as the AF system is not designed to operate under these conditions, and the EXIF data will not reflect the use of the extender. Some third-party extenders may not communicate extender information with the lens and camera at all, with the same effect as the aforementioned "tape trick".

The limitations discussed hereafter generally do not apply to third-party zoom lenses that have maximum apertures of f/6.3 at the long end of the zoom range, as they actually report a maximum aperture of f/5.6 to the camera. Note, though, that faster third-party lenses should be able to autofocus as expected for their aperture, including any high-precision focusing capability normally supported by the lens and body.

All images in this answer should be attributed to Canon Inc unless otherwise noted.

---

---

## APS-C cameras

---

### Canon EOS Digital Rebel (original, 300D), Digital Rebel XT (350D), Rebel XS (1000D), Rebel T3 (1100D), D30, D60, 10D

All points function to f/5.6; the center point is normal-precision cross-type (it is both vertical- and horizontal-sensitive to f/5.6 and is not high precision at f/2.8). All other points are single-line (EOS D30 and D60: vertical sensitive only). Autofocus does not function below f/5.6.

- EOS D30 and D60: 3 AF points available.
- EOS 10D, Digital Rebel (300D), Digital Rebel XT (350D), Rebel XS (1000D): 7 AF points available.
- EOS Rebel T3 (1100D): 9 AF points available.

[image: Canon EOS D30/D60 AF array]

 *Canon EOS D30/D60 AF array*

[image: Canon EOS 1000D AF array]

 *Canon EOS 1000D AF array*

<sup>The rectangles with longer sides horizontally oriented are vertical-sensitive.

The vertically oriented rectangles are horizontal-sensitive.

The square is sensitive both horizontally and vertically (cross-type).</sup>

Note that the EOS Rebel T3 (1100D) has essentially the same AF point layout as those in the next group of cameras, only that the center point is not high precision at f/2.8.

---

### Canon EOS Digital Rebel XTi (400D), Rebel XSi (450D), Rebel T1i (500D), Rebel T2i (550D), Rebel T3i (600D), Rebel SL1 (100D), Rebel T5 (1200D), Rebel T6 (1300D), 20D, 30D

All points function to f/5.6. The center point is cross-type, and all other points are single-line. The center point is high-precision dual cross-type with f/2.8 or faster lenses. Autofocus does not function with lenses narrower than f/5.6.

[image: Canon EOS Rebel T3i (600D) AF array]

 *Canon EOS Rebel T3i (600D) AF array*

[image: Canon EOS Rebel T1i and XSi AF point and position spacing]
*Canon EOS Rebel T1i and XSi AF point and position spacing*
<sup>Source: Long-time Canon Technical Advisor [Chuck Westfall](https://www.flickr.com/photos/33233371@N04/3442090828)</sup>

Note that the bold black and red rectangles with dots in the center are what actually appear in the viewfinder (all as black rectangles with dots in the center). The larger blue rectangles are the actual areas of coverage. Rectangles wider than tall are vertical-sensitive. Rectangles taller than wide are horizontal-sensitive.

---

### Canon EOS Rebel T4i (650D), Rebel T5i (700D), 40D, 50D, 60D

All points function as cross type to f/5.6. The center point is high-precision dual cross-type with f/2.8 or faster lenses. Autofocus does not function with lenses narrower than f/5.6. With the following lenses, the center point is normal-precision single cross-type, as if they were f/5.6 lenses:

- EF 28-80mm f/2.8-4L USM
- EF 50mm f/2.5 Compact Macro

With the following lenses, [the outside points of the AF array are single-line horizontal-sensitive, not cross-type](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_7D.aspx?faqtcmuri=tcm:14-822402&page=1&type=faq):

- EF 35-80mm f/4-5.6 (all variants)
- EF 35-105mm f/4-5.6 (original and original USM variants only)
- EF 80-200mm f/4.5-5.6 (II and USM variants only)

(EOS Rebel T4i (650D): Though not included in the above link, this limitation is specified in the [manual for this camera](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300007695/01/eosrt4i-eos650d-im-c-en.pdf), page 99.)

[image: Canon EOS 60D AF array]

 *Canon EOS 60D AF array*

---

### Canon EOS Rebel T6i (750D) and T6s (760D), 70D, 7D

The same aperture limits for the EOS Rebel T4i (650D), 40D, 50D, and 60D apply to the 7D, only that the 7D has 19 AF points instead of 9.

EOS 70D: The above applies to focusing when using the viewfinder. In Live View, with Dual Pixel CMOS AF, phase-detection autofocus with apertures as small as f/11 is possible across about 65% of the total frame area (80% height by 80% width). Dual Pixel CMOS AF is fully supported with more than 100 EF lenses, including all EF lenses currently in production. Other lenses will autofocus in a hybrid phase-detection/contrast-detection mode when in Live View.

Rebel T6i and T6s: Sensor-plane phase detection AF is available but only in a hybrid mode.

[image: Canon EOS 7D AF array]

 *Canon EOS 7D AF array*

---

### Canon EOS Rebel T7i (800D), 77D, 80D

*TODO: Expand with lens group information*

45 points are available at all apertures f/5.6 or wider, 27 at f/8. With certain exceptions, the following apply:

- If f/2.8 or wider, all 45 points are cross-type; additionally, the center point is high-precision dual cross-type.
- If f/5.6 or wider, all 45 points remain cross-type but the center point is standard-precision single cross-type.
- If f/8 or wider, 27 points remain available, 9 of which are cross-type. The remainder are horizontal-sensitive.
- Autofocus does not function with lenses narrower than f/8.

[image: Canon EOS 80D AF Array]

*Canon EOS 80D AF array*
<sup>Source: [Canon - Asia](https://snapshot.canon-asia.com/sg/article/eng/all-about-the-eos-80d-1-45-all-cross-type-af-points)</sup>

With f/8 lenses, the blue points are horizontal-sensitive only. The red points remain cross-type. The nine points along the top and bottom are not sensitive with f/8 lenses or lens + extender combinations.

[image: EOS 80D AF point sensitivity with f/8 lenses]

*EOS 80D AF point sensitivity with f/8 lenses*

<sup>Source: [Canon - Asia](https://snapshot.canon-asia.com/sg/article/eng/all-about-the-eos-80d-1-45-all-cross-type-af-points)</sup>

---

### Canon EOS 7D Mark II

[image: Canon EOS 7D Mark II AF array]

 *Canon EOS 7D Mark II AF array*

Autofocus capabilities depend on which of the seven groups the lens in use falls into (see the [EOS 7D Mark II manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300016615/01/eos7d-mk2-im-en.pdf)):

- **Group A:** Most f/2.8 and faster lenses and lens/extender combinations, with the exception of those listed in other groups below, support 65 cross-type points, including one high-precision dual cross-type point in the center of the array. All 65 AF points and AF area selection modes are available.

[image: Group A AF array: 65 points, 65 cross-type, 1 dual cross-type]

- **Group B:** Most f/5.6 and faster lenses and lens/extender combinations, with the exception of those listed in other groups below, support 65 cross-type points. The center point is normal-precision single cross-type. All 65 AF points and AF area selection modes are available. This group also includes the following lenses:

  - EF-S 60mm f/2.8 Macro (with neither IS nor USM)
  - EF 50mm f/2.5 Compact Macro (with or without Life-Size Converter)
  - EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM

[image: Group B AF array: 65 points, 65 cross-type]

- **Group C:** These lenses support *45* cross-type points; the outer ten points at each side of the AF array are horizontal-sensitive. All 65 AF points and AF area selection modes are available.

  - EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
  - EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 (all versions)
  - EF 20-35mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
  - EF 35-135mm f/4-5.6 USM
  - EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 USM (this version only; all other versions are in Group B)
  - EF 100-300mm f/4.5-5.6 USM

[image: Group C AF array: 65 points, 45 cross-type]

- **Group D:** These lenses support *25* cross-type points in the center; the outer points on the left and right side of the array are all horizontal-sensitive. All 65 AF points and AF area selection modes are available.

  - EF 24-85mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
  - EF 35-350mm f/3.5-5.6L USM
  - EF 55-200mm f/4.5-5.6 USM (both versions)
  - EF 80-200mm f/4.5-5.6 (original version, without USM)
  - EF 90-300mm f/4.5-5.6 (with and without USM)

[image: Group D AF array: 65 points, 25 cross-type]

- **Group E:** These lenses support 25 cross-type points in the center, but a *total* of *45* points are available. The outer ten points on each side of the AF array are disabled, and the remaining ten points on each side are horizontal-sensitive. All AF area selection modes are available.

  - EF-S 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
  - EF 28-70mm f/3.5-4.5 (both versions)
  - EF 28-80mm f/3.5-5.6 (all versions)
  - EF 35-70mm f/3.5-4.5
  - EF 35-70mm f/3.5-4.5A ([autofocus-only](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/are-there-dslr-lenses-that-dont-allow-for-manual-focus))
  - EF 35-80mm f/4-5.6 (II and PZ power zoom versions only)
  - EF 80-200mm f/4.5-5.6 (USM and II versions)
  - EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM (non-L version)
  - EF 800mm f/5.6L IS USM
  - EF 1200mm f/5.6L USM

[image: Group E AF array: 45 points, 25 cross-type]

- **Group F:** These lenses and lens/extender combinations support *15* cross-type points in the center, with a *total* of *45* points available. The outer ten points on each side of the AF array are disabled, the remaining ten points on each side are horizontal-sensitive, and the top and bottom five points in the center are vertical-sensitive. All AF area selection modes are available.

  - EF 22-55mm f/4-5.6 USM
  - EF 28-105mm f/4-5.6 (both versions)
  - EF 35-80mm f/4-5.6 (original, USM, and III versions)
  - EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM with Extender EF 1.4x

[image: Group F AF array: 45 points, 15 cross-type]

- **Group G:** Most f/8 lens/extender combinations, the sole exception being *EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM with Extender EF 2x* (with which autofocus does not function), support autofocus with the center point *only*, which is cross-type (all other points are disabled). AF point expansion can be used (although only the center point can be selected), with four points adjacent to the center point acting as AF assist points. The points above and below the center point are vertical sensitive, while the points to the left and right of the center point are horizontal sensitive. Autofocus does not function with lenses narrower than f/8. This group also includes the following lenses:

  - EF 35-105mm f/4.5-5.6 (with and without USM)

[image: Group G AF array: One cross-type point, plus four AF assist points when AF point expansion is enabled]

Dual Pixel CMOS AF, as in the EOS 70D, is also available.

Comment: Can't this all be found right on the Canon website?

Comment: This is all in the manuals, but it would be more convenient if there was a comprehensive list that can easily be found.  I decided to "seed" this question and answer to help Canon users with regard to what their lenses allow in terms of autofocus.

Comment: I can follow some of what you're saying here, but the words "autofocus does not function" must not mean what I think it does.  I pick up my 500D, set it to f/22, point it at something, and half-press the shutter, and it focuses for me.  I don't have to manually focus the camera.  What do you mean by it?

Comment: @khedron, autofocus occurs with the lens wide open. If the maximum aperture is within the limits given in the answer, AF will work with the capabilities and limitations given above. The maximum aperture is indicated on the lens. For example, you may see "1:3.5-5.6" for f/3.5-5.6, so the maximum aperture varies with the zoom setting.  The lens is stopped down only when you take a picture.

Comment: What about lenses that aren't manufactured by Canon? Does e.g. Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8 enable use of center high-precision point in xxxD/Rebels?

Comment: @Baczek: Yes, you should be able to get high-precision AF with this lens, as it reports f/2.8 to the camera.

Comment: Seems to be missing older models? Not so sure about the 3-point D30 and D60, nor the 1D/1Ds Mark I and II, but I believe the 10D, 20D, 300D, 350D, and 1000D all had standard (not high precision) cross-type centre-only, with the rest of their 7/9 points just horizontal or vertical, as per the current 1100D.

Comment: @drfrogsplat: Updated to add all Canon EOS DSLR cameras since the D30 and EOS-1D.  This revision comes out at just over 14,000 characters, slightly less than one half of the 30,000 character limit.

Comment: @DragonLord: The 7D is currently included with a bunch of other cameras, however it has a unique 19pt all-cross type AF system. Could you update to account for that?

Comment: @jrista: Updated for this as well.  The 7D and 650D/40D/50D/60D actually share the same set of limitations.

Comment: great work @DragonLord, amazingly thorough... if only I had more upvotes to give!

Comment: @jrista: I just noticed you (or another moderator) removed community wiki status from this post; gained +90 reputation after a rep recalc at http://photo.stackexchage.com/reputation. :)

Comment: Yeah, that was me. :) Thought you deserved the rep. Regarding the 7D's AF, it would be nice to describe it separately, and show the AF point layout image from Canon, like you did the rest.

Comment: @jrista: Added AF array images for all of the cameras. As of revision 40, the post contains 15,718 characters.

Comment: @DragonLord: Thanks! I wonder if you've made a record...

Comment: @jrista: According to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/photography/revision/82966/95479/), the longest answer, 21,676 characters, is http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/what-does-it-mean-for-a-photograph-to-be-high-key/10300#10300

Comment: This may all be in the manuals and the OP could have looked it up, but congratulations @DragonLord for bringing it all together in one place! A full and complete answer - probably way more than the OP expected, but definitely a comprehensive guide!  I +1'd but if I could + more I would... :)

Comment: I just wanna clarify something.. when you say "Canon DSLRs require a maximum aperture of at least f/5.6 to autofocus". That means the camera won't auto focus if you have a lens that has a bigger aperture than that, right? sorry, i'm new to this..

Comment: @ides: Terms that compare the size of apertures, such as "at least" and "below", refers to the actual size of the aperture.  Smaller f/numbers are consider to be greater than larger f/numbers, since they represent physically larger apertures. For example, f/4 is greater than f/5.6, and f/2.8 is below f/2.  As such, f/4, f/2.8, etc. are considered to be within the range defined by "at least f/5.6".

Comment: @DragonLord: oh sorry, let me rephrase. So a camera won't auto focus if you have a lens that has a smaller aperture than the one you specified? like f8, f10 etc... Please correct me if I'm wrong. hehe.

Comment: @ides: Yes.  This condition typically only arises when an extender is used.  Note that the relevant aperture value is the maximum aperture.  Even if your lens stops down to f/11, f/16, etc., what matters is the smallest f/number (largest aperture) the lens supports.

Comment: Ah. thanks! I was wondering a while back why the 1D won't AF at f8. Now I know.. Cheers!

Comment: @jrista: 21416 characters as of revision 64.

Comment: @jrista: Answer split for readability and length; see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr/56817#56817

Comment: Thanks, DL. Looks good to me. We just need to get some upvotes on the new one, so it floats to the top. ;)

Answer (score 12):

## Full frame and APS-H cameras

*For general information and APS-C cameras, see [the answer above](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr/16400#16400).*

---

### Canon EOS 6D

All points function to f/5.6. The center point is cross-type, and all other points are single-line. The center point is high-precision cross-type with f/2.8 or faster lenses (but is not dual cross-type as it does not have diagonal-line sensors). Autofocus does not function with lenses with a maximum aperture narrower than f/5.6.

[image: Canon EOS 6D AF array]
<sub>Note: the smaller black rectangles are what appear in the viewfinder. The larger blue and orange rectangles are the actual areas of coverage.</sub>

*Canon EOS 6D AF array*

---

### Canon EOS 5D and EOS 5D Mark II

All points function to f/5.6. The center point is cross-type, and all other points are single-line. The center point is high-precision cross-type with f/2.8 or faster lenses (but is not dual cross-type as it does not have diagonal-line sensors).

The invisible Assist AF points used in AI Servo AF function as horizontal-sensitive to f/5.6. With f/2.8 or faster lenses, two of these points function as cross-type.

Autofocus does not function narrower than f/5.6.

[image: Canon EOS 5D Mark II AF array]

 *Canon EOS 5D Mark II AF array*
<sub>The red "assist" points which are only active during *AI Servo AF* are not depicted in the viewfinder.</sub>

[image: Canon EOS 5D Mark II AF map]
<sub>Source: Long time Canon Technical Advisor [Chuck Westfall](https://www.flickr.com/photos/33233371@N04/3098752372/in/faves-39420162@N04/)</sub>

*Canon EOS 5D Mark II AF map* with notations that show the actual areas of sensitivity superimposed over the smaller bold rectangles that actually appear in the viewfinder. Vertical blue rectangles are horizontally sensitive while horizontal blue rectangles are vertically sensitive.

---

### Canon EOS-1D, EOS-1Ds, EOS-1D Mark II, EOS-1D Mark II N, EOS-1Ds Mark II

- If f/2.8 or wider, all 45 autofocus points will function, with 7 points high-precision cross-type.
- If f/4 or wider but narrower than f/2.8, all 45 autofocus points will function, but only the center point is high-precision cross-type.
- If f/5.6 or wider but narrower than f/4, all 45 autofocus points will function as horizontal sensitive only.
- If f/8 or wider but narrower than f/5.6, only the center point functions as horizontal sensitive only. The other points will not work.
- Autofocus does not function narrower than f/8.

Note that when using the *EF 70-200mm f/2.8L USM* lens (without IS) with an Extender, use the center point only as the other points may not focus correctly.

[image: Canon EOS-1D Mark II AF array]

*Canon EOS-1D Mark II AF array*

---

### Canon EOS-1D Mark III, EOS-1Ds Mark III, EOS-1D Mark IV

- If f/2.8 or wider, all 45 autofocus points will function, with 19 points high-precision cross-type.  (EOS-1D Mark IV only, with manual point selection: 39 of the 45 points are high-precision cross-type.)

[image: Canon EOS-1D Mark III AF array]

 *Canon EOS-1D Mark III AF array*

[image: Canon EOS-1D Mark IV AF array]

 *Canon EOS-1D Mark IV AF array*

- If f/4 or wider but narrower than f/2.8, all 45 autofocus points will function, but only the center point is high-precision cross-type.
- If f/5.6 or wider but narrower than f/4, all 45 autofocus points will function as horizontal sensitive only.
- If f/8 or wider but narrower than f/5.6, only the center point functions as horizontal sensitive only. The other points will not work.
- Autofocus does not function narrower than f/8.
- There are exceptions:

  - All of the AF points will be horizontal sensitive only if a variable-aperture zoom lens is mounted, with the exception of the *EF 28-80mm f/2.8-4L USM* lens, which allows the center point to work as cross-type.
  - EOS-1D Mark III and EOS-1Ds Mark III: When using the *EF 70-200mm f/2.8L USM* lens (without IS) with an Extender, use the center point only as the other points may not focus correctly.
  - The following lenses do not allow the three points on the far left and far right to work as cross-type points (only horizontal sensitive) even though they have a maximum aperture of f/2.8:

    - EF 24mm f/2.8
    - EF 28mm f/2.8
  - EOS-1D Mark IV only: Some lenses and lens/extender combinations enable cross-type focusing with 39 of the 45 points, even though they have a maximum aperture of f/4:

    - EF 17-40mm f/4L USM
    - EF 24-105mm f/4L IS USM
    - EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS USM with Extender EF 1.4X II
    - EF 200mm f/2L IS USM with Extender EF 2X II
    - EF 300mm f/2.8L IS USM with Extender EF 1.4X II
    - EF 400mm f/2.8L IS USM with Extender EF 1.4X II

---

### Canon EOS 5D Mark III, EOS 5Ds (R), EOS-1D X

[image: Canon EOS-1D X AF array]

 *Canon EOS-1D X AF array*

Autofocus capabilities depend on which of the eight groups the lens in use falls into (see [the Canon EOS-1D X AF Setting Guidebook](http://downloads.canon.com/cpr/software/camera/EOS_1DX_AF_Guide2.pdf), pages 36-39, and [Canon EOS 5D Mark III manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/01/eos5dmkiii-im-c-en.pdf), pages 79-84, for more details; a complete and easier-to-navigate list of lenses can be found [here](http://www.canon.com.hk/en/product/catalog/getProductTag.do?tagID=4538)):

- **Group A:** Most f/2.8 and faster lenses and lens/extender combinations, with the exception of those listed in Groups B, C, and D, support 41 cross-type points (21 in the center, f/5.6 sensitive, and 10 on each side, f/4 sensitive) and 5 dual cross-type points (in the center column, f/2.8 sensitive). The remaining points are horizontal-sensitive. All 61 AF points and AF area selection modes are available.

[image: Group A AF array: 61 points, 41 cross-type, 5 dual cross-type]

- **Group B:** These f/2.8 lenses allow the same functionality as Group A lenses except that only one point is f/2.8 dual cross-type:

  - EF 14mm f/2.8L USM
  - EF 14mm f/2.8L II USM
  - EF 15mm f/2.8 Fisheye
  - EF 20mm f/2.8 USM
  - EF 24mm f/2.8
  - EF 24mm f/2.8 IS USM
  - EF 28mm f/2.8 IS USM
  - EF 24-70mm f/2.8L USM (original variant only)

[image: Group B AF array: 61 points, 41 cross-type, 1 dual cross-type]

- **Group C:** Most f/4 lenses and lens/extender combinations support 41 cross-type points (none of the points are dual cross-type). All 61 AF points and AF area selection modes are available. A few macro lenses are in this group as well:

  - EF 50mm f/2.5 Compact Macro
  - EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro
  - EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM

[image: Group C AF array: 61 points, 41 cross-type]

- **Group D:** These f/2.8 lenses supports only *31* cross-type points (21 in the center, inner column of 5 on each side) and one f/2.8 dual cross-type point, although all 61 AF points and AF area selection modes are available.

  - EF 28mm f/2.8
  - EF 40mm f/2.8 STM (pancake lens introduced with EOS Rebel T4i)

[image: Group D AF array: 61 points, 31 cross-type, 1 dual cross-type]

- **Group E:** Most f/5.6 lens and lens/extender combinations support *21* cross-type points in the center (none of the side points are cross-type, and there are no dual cross-type points). All 61 AF points and AF area selection modes are available. A few macro lenses are in this group as well:

  - EF 50mm f/2.5 Compact Macro with Life-Size Converter EF
  - EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM

[image: Group E AF array: 61 points, 21 cross-type]

- **Group F:** These lenses support 21 cross-type points in the center, but a *total* of *47* points are available (seven points from the extremes at each side of the AF array are disabled), although all AF area selection modes are available:

  - EF 25-55mm f/4-5.6 USM
  - EF 28-70mm f/3.5-4.5 (all variants)
  - EF 28-80mm f/3.5-5.6 (all variants)
  - EF 28-105mm f/4-5.6 (original and original USM variants only)
  - EF 35-70mm f/3.5-4.5 (all variants)
  - EF 35-80mm f/4-5.6 (all variants)
  - EF 35-350mm f/3.5-5.6L USM
  - EF 80-200 f/4-5.6 (II and USM variants only)
  - EF 800mm f/5.6L IS USM

[image: Group F AF array: 47 points, 21 cross-type]

- **Group G:** These lenses and lens/extender combinations support *15* cross-type points in the center and a *total* of *33* points (the top and bottom three cross-type points in the center and 11 points from the extremes at each side of the AF array are disabled), although all AF area selection modes are available:

  - EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM
  - EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM with Extender EF 1.4x
  - EF 1200mm f/5.6L USM

[image: Group G AF array: 33 points, 15 cross-type]

- **Group H:** EOS-1D X with firmware version 1.1.1 or later, and EOS 5D Mark III with firmware version 1.2.1 or later (see [this page](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/EOS5DM3_firmware)): Most f/8 lens/extender combinations, the sole exception being *EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM with Extender EF 2x* (with which autofocus does not function), support autofocus with the center point *only*, which is cross-type (all other points are disabled). AF point expansion can be used (although only the center point can be selected), with four points adjacent to the center point acting as AF assist points. The points above and below the center point are vertical sensitive, while the points to the left and right of the center point are horizontal sensitive. Autofocus does not function narrower than f/8. This group also includes the following lenses:

  - EF 35-105mm f/4.5-5.6 (with and without USM)

[image: Group H AF array: One cross-type point, plus four AF assist points when AF point expansion is enabled]

EOS-1D X with firmware older than version 1.1.1 and EOS 5D Mark III with firmware older than version 1.2.1: Only the center point can be used (all other points are disabled) for the above EF 35-105mm lenses, and AF point expansion is not available. Autofocus does not function narrower than f/5.6.

[image: Group H AF array with older firmware: One cross-type point]

---

### Canon EOS-1D X Mark II and EOS 5D Mark IV

*TODO: Expand with lens group information*

The arrangement of autofocus points is identical to that of the original EOS-1D X, but with several key enhancements. 61 points are available at all apertures f/8 or wider. For the purpose of determining autofocus capabilities, lenses will be divided into twelve groups from A through L. The following capabilities are available, subject to limitations as determined by the group in which a lens is placed:

- If f/2.8 or wider, 41 cross-type points are available, including 20 f/4 enhanced precision cross-type points (ten at each side) and 5 high-precision dual cross-type points in the center column.
- If f/4 or wider but narrower than f/2.8, 41 cross-type points are available, 20 of which (ten at each side) have enhanced precision, but the center five points are *standard-precision* dual cross-type.
- If f/5.6 or f/8 or wider but narrower than f/4, 21 cross-type points are available in the center area. The side points are horizontal-line sensitive.
- Autofocus does not function narrower than f/8.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to point that the information about focus points in EOS 600D/550D/500D/450D might not be accurate.

" Canon EOS Digital Rebel XTi (400D), Rebel XSi (450D), Rebel T1i (500D), Rebel T2i (550D), Rebel T3i (600D), 30D

The center point is high-precision cross-type only when the aperture is at least f/2.8. If below f/2.8 but at least f/5.6, **all points function as either horizontal or vertical sensitive only (not both)**. Below f/5.6, autofocus does not function. "

Canon website :
"AF System/ Points 9 AF points (**f/5.6 cross type at centre**, extra sensitivity at f/2.8) "

Same is with 6D AF center point (f/5.6 cross type at centre, extra sensitivity at f/2.8), witch is same as in this article.

Comment: The center "point" is two sets of cross-type lines:  a set of vertical and horizontal pairs [+] sensitive at f/5.6 and a set of diagonal pairs [X] sensitive at f/2.8.

Answer (score 0):

A recent discovery -- the Kenko teleconverters allow for autofocus at F/8 on most (if not all) Canon bodies. See for instance Art Morris: http://www.birdsasart-blog.com/2012/08/30/mega-amazing-discovery-800-f5-6-1-4x-tc-canon-eos-1dx/

I've started experimenting with the combination of a Kenko 2.0x teleconverter and a Canon 300 F/4 lens, which gives me a 600mm/F8. My initial experiments show that this combination on a 7D does, in fact, enable autofocus.

It should be noted that the combination needs good light; it doesn't seem to work well in poor light. It's slow. It's not always consistent. but it works.

It's too early for me to decide whether or not this is a combo I'd trust in field conditions on a regular basis (my initial take on the image quality is that they're sharp enough but I find the images a bit overexposed and the contrast is weak. Both are fixable either by adjustments on the camera or in post, but are definitely going to need to be evaluated further).

It does, however, work, and give me a 600mm lens for < $1400 if bought new. And it works well enough to at least be worth experimenting with. The Kenko 1.4x might be an interesting experiment on some of the F5.6 lenses as Morris notes, too.

Comment: Answer updated to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently picked up a Yongnuo Extender 2X III, and tried it on my EF 400mm f/5.6L USM, and to my surprise the autofocus at f/11 actually works on both my 5D Mark IV and 5D Mark III bodies. I will point out I have not tried it in other than bright daylight; I expect it will fail as the light falls off, but normal daylight seems to allow these 2 bodies to continue to function. I did notice an odd thing on my Mark IV - I have to reduce my exposure by 2 stops compensation to get a balanced histogram, but the Mark III doesn't seem to have this issue. Further experimentation on my part might lead me to some reason for this. All in all, I was surprised by this result, and thinking it will help me as I sit in a field looking for those distant targets as long as they aren't moving too fast!

Comment: This isn't actually answering the question as asked; and is not specific to the Yongnuo tc (as you'll see by a similar answer about a Kenko). The only reason the camera AFs is that these 3rd party tcs don't report and don't see the max. aperture on the lens as being changed.