# How can i get AF confirmation working with Samyang 500mm f/6.3 with dandelion chip?

Tags: focus, diy, samyang, dandelion-chip, focus-confirmation

I've put a dandelion chip (4th gen) on my Samyang 500mm f/6.3. I shoot a Canon 6D by the way. So, that's cool now I've set the chip to return f/6.3 and I can get a correctly exposed LiveView, EXIF shows 500mm, that's nice. But the main thing I was looking for, the AF-confirm, is still not working.

As anyone tried this chip on this specific lens and successfully set the back/front focus correction?

Comment: are you saying that you get your AF beep/light but it is not accurate?

Comment: have you tried this?http://www.leitax.com/conversion/Chip/Dandelion-Canon-programming.html

Comment: Yep I tried. And no, I don't have any AF beep/light at all. The chip works as I tried it on an other lens and got the AF light. But somehow I don't have anything on this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you programmed the chip to return the correct maximum aperture of f/6.3, Autofocus on an EOS 6D is disabled, and therefore also AF-Confirm does not work. The AF-Sensors on this camera need at least a maximum Aperture of f/5.6 to work.

You can look at [this question and it's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/what-apertures-are-required-to-enable-autofocus-including-cross-type-or-high-pr) for more detailed information.

Comment: To compensate (if you think AF will actually work reliably with f/6.3 in a bright situation), you could set a fake aperture of f/5.6 and then use exposure compensation to adjust to the right exposure.  Then the camera would meter 'correctly' and on a bright situation you may get AF confirmation as well.

Comment: Guys, sorry for the long time of reply. I only saw your comments at the moment. Anyway thanks for your inputs, I'll try this ASAP and tell you what :). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly on Contax AX (an analogue camera) which has exclusive AF-function for C/Y-lenses, there is also f5.6 AF-limit, but (I proved it and had been confirmed about it) if using a catadioptic mirror lens beyond f.5.6 maybe f8 limited. AF is possible even in dim light like I had in the evening in the shop. Vivitar CAT 600/8.(nb: not that sharp but sharp enough above all with APS-C- have also a noname 300/5.6 which is in FC-testing. Many surprises using all kind of EOS-adapters. Also NI-EOS (all of them in MF-mode don't beep. Manuals tell which modes don't beep. Please concentrate on the signal first: green dot and focus-point(s) blinking).
Most important finding lately: I am slowly reentering FC-adventures. I had the beep, but all of a sudden it was gone: also no confirmation. Setting to selective helped. There must be another function which is switching this function.