# Why am I able to set wider aperture than my lens technically allows?

Tags: canon, aperture, sigma, superzoom

I'm practicing with Sigma 28 - 300mm f/3.5 - 6.3 Macro lens. And the thing I've noticed is that at 300mm focal length my aperture can be set to as wide as f/5.6. And EXIF data confirms it:

[image]

I'm wondering how is that technically possible and if the behavior is considered normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because [some cameras disable autofocus at slow apertures](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/why-does-canon-and-nikon-limit-or-disable-autofocus-beyond-certain-f-numbers).  The camera manufacturers think that performance won't be good enough, and so they disable it. The third-party lens is reporting inaccurate information to the camera so that it will work anyway — slow and sometimes incorrect, perhaps, but at least the camera will try.

Exposure might be off by a tiny bit as a result, but the third-stop difference between f/5.6 and f/6.3 basically comes out in the wash anyway.